# Blogger: Image blurry after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

Image blurry problem after resizing
You can see this in the three major images under Header
This is a preview of the blog link:
[Click Here](http://elmofedtech.blogspot.com)

I hope you help me with this and thank you .....

Comment: Define *«jamming»* in more details please...

Comment: i mean the blur on the images after i resize it

Comment: you have a lot of code errors, you should fix them https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Felmofedtech.blogspot.com%2F

Comment: if you disabled the (  .mainPosts li
.item-thumbnail a:before  ) you can see the blur...

Comment: @mlegg: most of the error found by the validator are inherent to blogspot...

Comment: Is that not editable in Blogspot? EDIT: a Google search shows you can edit it all.

Comment: @mlegg: that is editable... But usually users aren't skilled enought to do it. When they are, they stop using blogspot (lol). But that is out of scope of OP question. I don't think an error is the source of his problem, still unclear to me.

Comment: thank you @mlegg , im trying to fix this problems

Comment: someone gives me a jQuery code that fixes this problem editing some thing in the src but it now lost and i need it....

Comment: The images are [tiny](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XTfbpsdAddE/U0lqCHXEJqI/AAAAAAAAD9k/F2w3e1_Izgk/w72-h72-p-k-no-nu/artworks-000045993824-6c1mr9-t500x500.jpg) unless they are called with [correct size](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XTfbpsdAddE/U0lqCHXEJqI/AAAAAAAAD9k/F2w3e1_Izgk/w500-h500-p-k-no-nu/artworks-000045993824-6c1mr9-t1500x1500.jpg)

Comment: I taught that was after window resizing... But turns out that is after image resizing (width/height). Good catch @mplungjan ;)

Comment: I found the code but,I can't understand what the code means...: (                                        $('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {return src.replace(/s35-c|s72-c|s400|s640|w72-h72-p-nu/gi, 's640' );});
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to a problem which is:

If you look at the image link on Google:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PzbxBDHLdXQ/U1Bv9to15rI/AAAAAAAD_G/rWHFo52TF3I/w72-h72-p-k-no-nu/chicago_sunset-1280x720.jpg

You'll find:

(  **w72-h72-p-k-no-nu**  )
In the link and this is what the following code replaces it with something else

```
$ ('img'). attr ('src', function (i, src){return src.replace (/s35-c|s72-c|s400|s640|w72-h72-pk-no-nu|w72-h72-p-nu/gi, 's640');});
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. The solution I found was to upload it with original size and then resize using width="x%". Also un need to make sure that the actual width is given in

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-nkKVCjgXQyM/W9m3fm0yCeI/AAAAAAAAIHg/MuOoXXJ9oggo6w4DiTJwuCIhSL8crDMYgCLcBGAs/**s1600**/FC%2BBarcelona%2BFixtures-%2BNovember%2B2018.jpg

you need to make sure the actual width is given in there.